# React Native - How to wait for data then render screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm calling data with a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(id);
  }, []);
```

Then fetching data and updating state with useReducer dispatch like this:

```
const fetchData = dispatch => async props => {
  const id = props;
  await axios
    .get(`${URL}?id=${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;

      const isAuth = data[0].isAuth;
      const dataDetails = data[1].dataDetails;
      const dataTracks = data[2].dataTracks;

      dispatch({type: 'dataDetails', payload: dataDetails});
      dispatch({type: 'dataTracks', payload: dataTracks});
      dispatch({type: 'isAuth', payload: isAuth});
    });
};
```

Then rendering data like this:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView >
      <View >
        {state.dataDetails ? (
          <Text>
            {'@' + state.dataDetails.username}
          </Text>
        ) : null}
        <View/>
      </View>
      <View >
        <FlatList
          data={state.dataDetails.Tracks}
          ListHeaderComponent={ <DataDetails />}
          renderItem={({item}) => <PostTracks item={item} />}
        ></FlatList>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

I'm suppose to display username that i'm getting from data in a header and displaying the rest of the data in a Flatlist but it's not rendering anything.

When I console.log data it first returns undefined, then returns data

How can I make it so that it waits for data to load before it renders the screen?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need create a loading, like this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState()
```

In your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(id);
  }, [id]);
```

In `fetchData` function, you will change `loading` variable, like this:

```
const fetchData = dispatch => async props => {
  setLoading(true);
  const id = props;
  await axios
    .get(`${URL}?id=${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data;

      const isAuth = data[0].isAuth;
      const dataDetails = data[1].dataDetails;
      const dataTracks = data[2].dataTracks;

      dispatch({type: 'dataDetails', payload: dataDetails});
      dispatch({type: 'dataTracks', payload: dataTracks});
      dispatch({type: 'isAuth', payload: isAuth});
      setLoading(false)
    });
};
```

Afterward, you use `loading` to render the screen:

```
return (
 {
    loading ? <>loading</>
    : <SafeAreaView >
      <View >
        {state.dataDetails ? (
          <Text>
            {'@' + state.dataDetails.username}
          </Text>
        ) : null}
        <View/>
      </View>
      <View >
        <FlatList
          data={state.dataDetails.Tracks}
          ListHeaderComponent={ <DataDetails />}
          renderItem={({item}) => <PostTracks item={item} />}
        ></FlatList>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
}
    
  );
```

If that component without  the `fetchData` function, the `fetchData` function can returns a `new promise`, like the following function:

```
const fetchData = dispatch => props => {
  const id = props;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(`${URL}?id=${id}`).then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      resolve(data);
      const isAuth = data[0].isAuth;
      const dataDetails = data[1].dataDetails;
      const dataTracks = data[2].dataTracks;

      dispatch({ type: 'dataDetails', payload: dataDetails });
      dispatch({ type: 'dataTracks', payload: dataTracks });
      dispatch({ type: 'isAuth', payload: isAuth });
    })
    .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Then, in your `useEffect`, you can change value of `loading` state by the following way:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await fetchData
        .then((res) => {
          if (res) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => setLoading(false));
    };
    getData();
  }, [id]);
```

You can try change this way.

Comment: I don't have the fetchData function inside the same component im rendering the data in though. How would I go about adding useState?

Comment: I changed my post. You can check it! @jdez

Answer (score 0):

Put your `id` in dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(id);
}, [id]);
```

Since your dependency array is empty, the `useEffect` only runs once.

If you put your variable in dependency array, the `useEffect` will run  again when variable changed. Thus, the view will re-render.

Answer (score 0):

add loading in reducer

```
initialState = {
dataDetails:[],
dataTracks : [],
isAuth :[],
...
loading: false
}
```

then in

```
      const fetchData = dispatch => async props => {


              //set loading state : true
             dispatch({type: 'loading', payload: true});
        
              const id = props;
              await axios
                .get(`${URL}?id=${id}`)
                .then(res => {
                  const data = res.data;

...
                // after requset finishd and data loaded set loading :false
                  dispatch({type: 'loading', payload: false});
                }).catch(
                  // in case of error
                  dispatch({type: 'loading', payload: false});
        );
            };
```

then

```
  {state.loading ?( <View>
    <FlatList
      data={state.dataDetails.Tracks}
      ListHeaderComponent={ <DataDetails />}
      renderItem={({item}) => <PostTracks item={item} />}
    ></FlatList>
  </View>): <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#0000ff" />}
```